# Another way of matrix computation? Is there some decomposition involved?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a LxM matrix A and a MxN matrix B. I can multiply them a I have learned by taking the rows of A and the columns of B and take the inner product of them.

But I can also do it in another way. I see in A columns and in B rows. Then I take the Kronecker product of the first column of A and the first row of B, which gives a matrix. I do the same for the second column of A and the second row of B and add this resulting matrix to the first one. Do this for all columns of A and rows of B and add the resulting matrices. You will get the matrix product of A and B.

Example:

```
A=(1 2)  B=(4 3)
  (3 4)    (2 1)

(1)*(4 3)=(4  3)   (2)*(2 1)=(4 2)
(3)       (12 9)   (4)       (8 4)
```

Add:

```
(8   5)
(20 13)
```

I there some decomposition involved?

Comment: This is block matrix multiplication applied to the partitioning $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_m\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_m\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So in my example A has 1 row (with 2 blocks) and B has 1 column (with 2 blocks). Well, the Kronecker product was new for me in this situation.